# Displaying constants in HTML via Input/Output?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, output

`list.component`, which has an input variable tasks and listtype, which can be upcoming or completed. The `@Output`(s) are used if the task is checked (to become completed) and tasksChange, to change a task:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Map, List} from 'immutable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-list',
  templateUrl: 'task-list.component.html'
})
export class TaskListComponent  {
  @Input() tasks: string[] = [];
  @Input() listType: 'upcoming' | 'completed' = 'upcoming';
  @Output() itemChecked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() tasksChange: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter();



  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Is called when an item from the list is checked.
   * @param selected---Value which indicates if the item is selected or deselected.
   */
  onItemCheck(selected: boolean) {
    this.itemChecked.emit(selected);
  }

  /**
   * Is called when task list is changed.
   * @param changedTasks---Changed task list value, which should be sent to the parent component.
   */
  onTasksChanged(changedTasks: string[]) {
    this.tasksChange.emit(changedTasks);
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to display upcoming tasks with my `upcoming-tasks.component`, which has 3 mock tasks:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TaskListComponent} from "../task-list/task-list.component";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-upcoming-tasks',
  templateUrl: './upcoming-tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upcoming-tasks.component.css']
})
export class UpcomingTasksComponent extends TaskListComponent {
  upcomingTasks: string[] = ['bla', 'blub', 'bap'];

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and the HTML of the `upcoming-tasks.html`:

```
<h1>Upcoming Tasks</h1>
<app-task-list [(tasks)]="upcomingTasks" [listType]="'upcoming'" (itemChecked)="onItemCheck($event)"></app-task-list>
```

So what am I missing to get these tasks on my UI?

Comment: Please also show `task-list.component.html` and remove `extends TaskListComponent`

Comment: the task list html is empty, and when i remove the extension, the method onItemCheck cant be found

Comment: You are mixing the child and the parent here. A component should never extend another component. They have their relation defined in template as DOM child+parent. If a function can't be found the responsibility is not clear.

Comment: well the task-list.component should be the parent, and upcoming-... the child. How do i define them so?